# How to set AppCheck Debug token for Android Device?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I am currently switching our Flutter App from the AppCheck `SafetyNet` provider to the `PlayIntegrity` Provider.

Now I can't connect to Firebase any longer from all our development devices (real phones, no emulator) as the debug builds are not coming from the PlayStore.

I already set up to use the `DebugProvider` and added the DebugToken in Firebase and this is basically working.

When I use the same device with another computer and install the app again, the app is first uninstalled and reinstalled. This wipes all app information from the device and with it the Debug Token. So now I have to set up another debug token in Firebase and the old one is invalid.

Is there any way to provide a specific debug token in Android e.g. via an environment variable or like it is done for [Flutter Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider#web), that a specific token can be registered by setting `self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN` to the tokenString?

In [DebugAppCheckProvider.java](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/appcheck/firebase-appcheck-debug/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/appcheck/debug/internal/DebugAppCheckProvider.java) it seems there is no way to do this, but perhaps I am missing something?

The `DebugProvider` is mentioned in the Documentation always with emulators but not with real devices. Is this the normal way to use App Check when developing or is there another way to use it with my real devices?

Comment: To circumvent the issue, I now use the same debug.keystore on all my devices. Now the app is not uninstalled every time I switch my PC.

Comment: we are facing exactly same issue while testing on real devices. It is impractical to configure debug token like this with every installation on the same device.

There must be some better way.